# DotLiquid/Liquid access to dictionary

Tags: c#, liquid, dotliquid

I am using [DotLiquid](http://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/) template engine and trying access dictionary value in template.
I have passed to template this drop:

```
public class SomeDrop : Drop
{
   public Dictionary<string, object> MyDictionary {get; set;}
}

var someDropInstance = SomeDrop 
{
   MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"myKey", 1}}
}

Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();

var preparedTemplate = Template.Parse(template);
var templateOutput = preparedTemplate.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { @this = someDropInstance }));
```

In template i can't access to myKey value as 
`{{ this.MyDictionary.myKey }}` 
neither as 
`{{ this.MyDictionary['myKey'] }}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `Template.NamingConvention` before creating any drop objects. For performance reasons, the base `Drop` constructor [caches](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Drop.cs#L68) all public instance members using the current naming convention. Even if you then change the naming convention, those cached properties are not reset.

This code works for me:

```
public class SomeDrop : Drop
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void StackOverflow()
{
    Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
    const string template = "{{ this.MyDictionary.myKey }}";

    var someDropInstance = new SomeDrop
    {
        MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "myKey", 1 } }
    };

    var preparedTemplate = Template.Parse(template);
    Assert.That(
        preparedTemplate.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { @this = someDropInstance })),
        Is.EqualTo("1"));
}
```

I admit this is a bit of a gotcha - this is not the [first](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dotliquid/6XDW17YpqLI/discussion) time this issue has been raised. I haven't yet come up with a satisfactory solution, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just access it like `MyDictionary["myKey"]` or `MyDictionary.TryGetValue("myKey", out result)`. No extra `{{ }}`.

Comment: No extra `{{ }}` are present in template. Full template looks like `{{this.MyDictionary["myKey"]}}`. Still no joy.

Comment: OK. Shouldn't the dictionary be instantiated like `MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "myKey", 1 } };`. You declare it as dict but assign an array.

Comment: Is it possible to see the code generated from these templates by DotLiquid?

Comment: No, DotLiquid does not generate code; it's a string templating system.