# DotLiquid: Loop through a (Wrapped) Dictionary<string, string> in for-loop in template

Tags: c#, dictionary, liquid, dotliquid

As far as I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153929/dotliquid-liquid-access-to-dictionary), DotLiquid (using Version 1.8.0.0) does not support C# `Dictionary` constructs out of the box. They must be wrapped in a `Drop`-Object.

So I tried to adapt the Answer of Tim Jones for my use-case. Sadly, this is not working as expected, So I hope someone could show me where I'm going wrong here, for I am out of Ideas.

This is (one of) my wrapped model class containing a Dictionary:

```
public class LegendAdditive : Drop
{
    public LegendAdditive() 
    {
        AdditiveDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> AdditiveDict { get; set; }
}
```

The class itself is embedded in a `LegendModel` containing some other values:

```
public class LegendModel: Drop
{
    ...
    public LegendAdditive Additives { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, all the Classes are wrapped to be a `Drop`, which as I know is a prerequisite for using Dictionaries (Implementing ILiquidizable and so on).

In a converter, this Model is filled like this:

```
public DotLiquid.Drop GetModel(MyObject plan) 
{
    ...
    var LegendAdditives = new LegendAdditive();

    //dbLegend.Additives is a Dictionary<string, string> itself.
    if (dbLegend.Additives.Any())
        foreach (var additive in dbLegend.Additives.OrderBy(a => a.Key))
            LegendAdditives.AdditiveDict.Add(additive.Key, additive.Value);

   ...

    LegendModel model = new LegendModel
    {
        ...
        Additives = LegendAdditives,
        ...
    };

    return model; 
}
```

And in a class `ConvertToPdf`, I have a `ConvertTemplate` Method like this, parsing the template:

```
public static string ConvertTemplate(ITemplateFileFactory templateFilePathFactory IDropModelConverter modelConverter, MyObject mplan)
{
    //reading my filepath out of the factory here...

    DotLiquid.Template.NamingConvention = new DotLiquid.NamingConventions.CSharpNamingConvention();

    Template templateObj = Template.Parse(template);  // Parses and compiles the template
    Drop plan = modelConverter.GetModel(mplan);
    Hash hashedValues = Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { plan });
    string ret = templateObj.Render(hashedValues);
    return ret;
}
```

And finally in my Templatefile, I try to get the Values of this Dictionary like this:

```
<div>
    <dl>
        {% for add in plan.Additives.AdditiveDict %}
        <dt>{{add.Key}}</dt>
        <dd>{{add.Value}}</dd>
        {% endfor %}
    </dl>
</div>
```

Now the file is parsing correctly, but all I get for now is this output when I try to access the Dictionaryvalues in my loop:

```
Liquid syntax error: Object '[18, Stärke]' is
invalid because it is neither a built-in type
nor implements ILiquidizable
```

Now it seems that I actually *get* the correct Values in my Template.Parse Method. I'm just not getting them out of my structure, because...? Any help is appreciated. To be honest, I think I am missing something fundamentally here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `KeyValuePair<T>`, which you're trying to access the `Key` and `Value` properties of, is neither a `Drop` nor implements `ILiquidizable`.

If you want to loop through the items in your dictionary like that, you'll have to create a `KeyValueDrop` wrapper, and expose a `List` of that, instead of a dictionary.